# Add new Custom JSP Page to Zimbra mail server

Tags: jsp, jetty, zimbra

I am Java developer and want to add new public custom JSP Page to zimbra .
I create simple jsp and put on /opt/zimbra/jetty/webapps/zimbra/public and create a link from login.jsp to them .
put zimbra system filtered this page and can not access to them 
how can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that. just add your page in `/opt/zimbra/jetty/webapps/zimbra/example.jsp` and in `/opt/zimbra/jetty/webapps/zimbra/public/login.jsp` link to this page. You must to change `zimbra.web.xml.in` in `/opt/zimbra/jetty/etc` and add your Servlet to mapping exmaple.jsp. finally `zmmailboxdctl restart`